# The differences of scanf("%[^\n]",name); and scanf(" %[^\n]",name);

Tags: c, scanf, difference

It's not a typo. And for the one who doesn't notice, there is a space on the second one, and no space on the first.

It happens to me when i make a homework like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int id,d,m,y;
char name[30];
printf("\tSTUDENT ID\t\t: ");scanf("%d",&id);\
printf("\tNAME\t\t: ");scanf("%[^\n]",&name);
printf("\tDATE OF BIRTH\t: ");scanf("%d/%d/%d",&d,&m,&y);
}
```

when i do that code, the "NAME" part get skip to inputting "DATE OF BIRTH" part

But, when i change the scanf("%[^\n]",&name); into scanf(" %[^\n]",&name);
everything works fine.

How this could happen? I don't seem to understand the differences

Note: You can try it, and tell me is it works fine on yours, cause maybe its just my computer problem or something

Comment: The presented code is inherently unsafe. Use `std::getline` from `<string>`. For example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What is `std::getline`? The C standard has no such function, I think.

Comment: @JensGustedt: It's a C++ thing. At the time of that comment the question was tagged C++. Someone thought it was a good idea with an edit that changed the nature of the question slightly.

Comment: Yeah i was tagged it with c++, cause i m working my homework in c++

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Why would my code is unsafe. What kind of trouble will it makes that made you say that it's unsafe?

Comment: @Ronzy: For example, if the input line is longer than 30 characters then `scanf` will store data in arbitrary memory locations after the array, called a **buffer overflow**.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ahh ic ic...  Btw, i just learn about the fflush(stdin) function.. My question is, will fflush(stdin) will solve **buffer overflow**?

Comment: @Ronzy: `fflush` has nothing to do with buffer overflow. The technical problem there is that `scanf` has its original C interface also in C++, and with that interface there is no way for it to know the buffer size. But you can *tell it*. You can specify a [field width](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) for the input operation. Of course, in C++ an alternative is to use `std::getline` from the `<string>` header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put a space in a [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) formatting string, then [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) will match it with any whitespace, of any length. So by putting that leading space in the format, [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) will in effect skip leading whitespace in the input (which includes the newline from the previous input).

Example:

Lets say the input for your simple program is

```
123
Joe Bloggs
22/9/15
```

The first call to `scanf` read the number `123`, but leaves the newline you enter to end that line of input in the input buffer. When you next call `scanf` to get the name, then `scanf` will first see that newline  end return immediately (without consuming it, so it will still be in the input buffer). Then you call `scanf` to read the date, and the `"%d"` format automatically skip leading whitespace, so `scanf` will consume the newline, but then see the name and it will not match the format for decimal integers and exit, not reading the data.

By adding that leading space to the format when reading the name, the second `scanf` call will read (and ignore) the newline from the previous input, and then read the name properly, leaving the terminating newline from the second line in the input buffer which is then skipped by the next call to `scanf` which properly reads the date.

Answer (score 2):

There are three standard format specifiers for the [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) family of functions that do not automatically skip white space.  They are:

1. `%c`
2. `%[]` — scan sets
3. `%n`

All other (standard) format specifiers skip leading white space.

By including the white space before `%[]`, you skip leading white space, because a single white space in the `scanf()` family format string (outside a scan set) matches zero or more white space characters in the input.  Note, in particular, that this means that if you type some blank lines (just hit return), the white space will continue merrily ignoring (more accurately, discarding) the input until a non-white-space character is entered.  Only then will `scanf()` start processing the scan set.